# Conditional image in SEO in Gatsby JS

Tags: image, conditional-statements, seo, gatsby

I'm facing a problem with SEO in Gatsby JS. I have added the below code in my SEO.jsx file. I'm facing a problem with the SEO image. When I call the SEO component on a page and don't call **pageImage** then the image is not showing. Then I checked the source code and there is showing only the site link and in the place of **pageImage** there is showing **undefined**.

`` <meta name="image" content={`${siteUrl}${pageImage}` || `${siteUrl}${image}`} /> ``

But I want that, if I don't call **pageImage** then default **image** will call and there will be an image. How can I do that? What is my mistake in this code?

Comment: `\`${siteUrl}${pageImage}\`` will never be empty. What you want is `siteUrl + (pageImage || image)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  <meta name="image" content={`${siteUrl}${pageImage ? pageImage : image}`  />
```

You just need simply to move the condition (a ternary in this case) inside your template literal. You control value is `pageImage`, if it exists, it will render it, if don't it will use `image` instead.